# Confusion regarding notation in Alfsen's proof of Haar's existence theorem.

Tags: notation, harmonic-analysis, haar-measure

I am working through Alfen's proof that there exists a unique Haar measure on any locally compact group. There are a few propositions which have an unexplained notation which I am not familiar with - I think the notation is now outdated (the article is from 1963).

*Alfsen, Erik M.*, [**A simplified constructive proof of the existence and uniqueness of Haar measure**](http://dx.doi.org/10.7146/math.scand.a-10675), Math. Scand. 12 (1963), 106-116 (1964). [ZBL0274.43001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0274.43001).

In particular, I am not familiar with the notation $f_i^{\uparrow}f$ used in Corollary following Proposition 1.2 (page 108). What is the upward arrow meant to denote? It seems like notation to mean convergence, however I thought $f_i\rightarrow f$ would have been written then.

I am also not sure what is meant by $(f-1/n)^{+}$ in Proposition 2.3 (page 110). Does this simply mean the positively valued parts of $f-1/n$?

Comment: I think $f_i \uparrow f$ means that $f_i$ converges to $f$. I would guess from a quick look at the paper that $(f - 1/n)^+$ means $ \max(f - 1/n, 0)$, but that is just a wild guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_n \uparrow f$ is common notation for "$f_n$ increases to $f$".  That is, $(f_n)$ is a sequence of functions such that $f_1 \le f_2 \le f_3 \le \dots$, and $(f_n)$ converges to $f$.  Usually this means pointwise convergence unless otherwise specified, and that makes sense in this context.  An alternative notation for this is $f_n \nearrow f$.

Yes, $(f-1/n)^+$ means the [positive part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_and_negative_parts) of the function $f-1/n$, i.e. $\max(f-1/n, 0)$.

I would say these are both still in widespread use and I wouldn't call them outdated.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this for me. Perhaps I have never seen this notation before because I am still fairly new to graduate-level material.